# How to handle a case when the hard disk drive letter is not the same when saved it to a text file?

Tags: c#, winforms

in the constructor :

```
    SaveLoadFiles.LoadFile(textBoxRadarPath, "radarpath.txt");
SaveLoadFiles.LoadFile(textBoxSatellitePath, "satellitepath.txt");

if (textBoxRadarPath.Text != "" || textBoxSatellitePath.Text != "")
            {
                if(!Directory.Exists(textBoxRadarPath.Text))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(textBoxRadarPath.Text);
                }

                if (!Directory.Exists(textBoxSatellitePath.Text))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(textBoxSatellitePath.Text);
                }

                btnStart.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
             btnStart.Enabled = false;
            }
```

the SaveLoadFiles class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Weather
{
    public class SaveLoadFiles
    {
        public static void SaveFile(string contentToSave, string fileName)
        {
            string applicationPath = Path.GetFullPath(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory); // the directory that your program is installed in
            string saveFilePath = Path.Combine(applicationPath, fileName);
            File.WriteAllText(saveFilePath, contentToSave);
        }

        public static void LoadFile(TextBox loadTo, string fileName)
        {
            string applicationPath = Path.GetFullPath(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory); // the directory that your program is installed in
            string saveFilePath = Path.Combine(applicationPath, fileName); // add a file name to this path.  This is your full file path.

            if (File.Exists(saveFilePath))
            {
                loadTo.Text = File.ReadAllText(saveFilePath);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

when i used the application before and backed it up on my usb flash drive the second hard drive letter was D i had two hard disks : C and D and the project and the folders were on drive D.

now i backed up the project including the saved files but now my hard disks letters are C and E there is no D

but in the constructor when it's reading the text files the folders in the text files are D:....etc

but it should be E:

I'm checking if the folder exist or not and then if not creating it but it's trying to create the folder on drive D and D is not existing.

Comment: In WinForms, the Application's starting directory is returned by `Application.StartupPath`. You're using something similar (though redundant) in your methods, why are you picking these paths from TextBoxes and what do these TextBoxes contain? Some hard-coded paths? If so, then don't hard-code those paths

Comment: what is `System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` giving you? Regardless, you probably should not be writing data to the application folder. That's often read only. You want to use the AppData folder.  `Application.LocalUserAppDataPath`

Comment: @Jimi it isn't reading from the TextBoxes. It is just putting the filenames there after. The filename is shown in the code as a simple filename.

Comment: @GarrGodfrey Maybe I wasn't that clear, I'm referring to this: `if (textBoxRadarPath.Text != "" || textBoxSatellitePath.Text != "") { ... }` etc. -- You're right about the path itself, it should be `Application.CommonAppDataPath` or `Application.UserAppDataPath`, since you may not have write access to the startup folder (in case the application is installed, as often happens, in `Program Files` or similar)

Comment: Oh...we are both wrong. It's reading contents from a data file and using the contents of the data file as the path of folders to create. Yeah, the solution is don't do that kind of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading contents of a data file that has a file path that no longer exists.

The solution is to edit those data files: "radarpath.txt" and "satellitepath.txt" to have the proper path.

An application would normally provide a UI for selecting the folder to use, rather than saving a hardcoded path in a datafile. What you could do is use FileDialog to prompt the user for the directories to use if they don't exist.